# Script for a for moving a large database in Rackspace - Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, syntax, cron, rackspace-cloud

I have no experience in Perl. We are trying to move our 250MB database into MySQL with a Perl script that is scheduled as a Cron Job The Rackspace cloud has recommend this script:

> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> mysql -h DB_HOST -u DB_USER -p'DB_PASSWORD' DB_NAME < /path/to/file/db_import.sql
> ```

I have filled in the variables as so (user and pass have changed for this post):

> !/bin/sh mysql -h mysql51-032.wc1:3306 -u 806637_Admin -p
>   '***********' 806637_Vs_Hl <
>   /mnt/stor09-wc1-ord1/762283/806637/www.vs-hl.com/Vs-hlDB/Vs-DB.sql

Doing some research I found that the '#' starts a comment in Perl so I removed it and this is what I received as an error report:

> Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 1, near
>   "/bin/sh"     (Missing operator before h?)
>
> Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 1, near
>   "806637_VMHAdmin"     (Missing operator before VMHAdmin?)
>
> Number found where operator expected at main.pl line 1, near
>   "'Admin1234' 806637_"     (Missing operator before  806637_?)
>
> Bareword found where operator expected at main.pl line 1, near
>   "806637_Vets_Hall"    (Missing operator before Vets_Hall?)
>
> syntax error at main.pl line 1, near "/bin/sh mysql "
>
> Execution of main.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

My question is what am I doing wrong syntax wise? 
Thanks for reading!

Comment: You have done more than that: you also removed a `#` character and a newline character. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a Perl script, that's a Bourne Shell script. Just move it onto two separate lines.

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql ...
```

Note that the `#!` has to be the very first two characters of the file. No blank lines may proceed it.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl "script" and shell script are not the same things. So when dealing with programmers, I call it a "Perl program" since Perl is a fully functional programming language. This is a shell script which uses 2 separate lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysql ...
```

That has nothing to do with Perl. If you want to execute a command in Perl you can do this inside a Perl program. I'll call it doit.pl:

```
# Note I'm using backticks, and any error msgs are in $msg. 
$msg=`mysql -h DB_HOST -u DB_USER -p'DB_PASSWORD' DB_NAME < /path/to/file/db_import.sql`;
print "Messages are: $msg\n";
```

And you don't need Perl if nothing in the command line changes. You could use Perl if you are looping through and copying many database names though.